# c# bookmark .zip file embedded object

Tags: c#, ms-word, bookmarks

I want to add  zip files to my word document with bookmark embedded.
I can add .pdf, .doc, .txt or .xls file but i can not add  .zip files to my word document. How can i do this? Is it class type problem?

```
 Bookmark bmEmbedded = doc.Bookmarks["ek10"];
                                bmEmbedded.Select();
                                object classType = "Word.Document.12";

                                if (uzanti.Contains(".doc")) classType = "Word.Document.15";
                                else if (uzanti.Contains(".xls")) classType = "Excel.Sheet";
                                else if (uzanti.Contains(".txt")) classType = "Text Document";
                                **else if (uzanti.Contains(".msg")) classType = "Outlook.Item";**
                                else if (uzanti.Contains(".pdf") || uzanti2.Contains(".pdf")) classType = "AcroRd32.Document";


                                    wordApp.Selection.Range.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject(ClassType: classType, FileName: embeddedFilePath2, DisplayAsIcon: true, LinkToFile: false, IconFileName: labelControl64.Text);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to embed a file in a Word document an `OLE Server` is required. These are applications that are listed in the Registry as being OLE Servers for a certain file type. Excel, for example, is registered as the OLE Server for `xlsx` files.

If there is no available OLE Server Word *can* embed a file as a generic "Package". Whether this can be successfully "unpacked" at a later time is uncertain, however.

In order to determine the code required for embedding any type of file, the surest way is to record a macro while inserting the file in Word. On my machine, if I embed a `zip` file the recorded code is:

```
    Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject ClassType:="CompressedFolder", _
      fileName:="C:\Test\CalcIfFields.docx.zip", LinkToFile:=False, _
      DisplayAsIcon:=False
```

Whether this will work in your environment I cannot know...